# Python - read excel file into a list and rename files in a folder

Tags: python, excel, rename, openpyxl, shutil

We have an excel file with 2094 rows and 3 columns structured like so:

> Employee Old ID | Employee Name | Employee New ID
>
> 007219 | John Doe | 001234
>
> The end result being: John Doe 001234.jpg

We have a folder with employee photos labels by their Old IDs and we want to read the excel file and then copy and rename the photos with the new ID.

**Issue with the code** - it stops after it copies and renames the first photo. I presume I need to adjust the last for loop but I am drawing a blank on how to get it to iterate.

*Notes: I tried to make the code flexible by including a file dialog folderSource. Additionally, I am new to Python so if you see ways to clean up the code by all means let me know, I added some questions in the comments in the code:*

```
import openpyxl
import os
import shutil
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# File with file name data
# Add the file name
file_names = openpyxl.load_workbook(filedialog.askopenfilename())
# Add the sheet name - can you make this more flexible? 
file_names_sheet = file_names['piclist2']  

# Select the source folder with files in it
folderSource = filedialog.askdirectory()

# New Folder Name - is there a filedialog way to flexibly create this?
folderDestination = 'SSL Photos Renamed'

# Takes: start cell, end cell, and sheet you want to copy from.
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    # Loops through selected Rows
    for i in range(startRow, endRow + 1, 1):
    # Appends the row to a RowSelected list
        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol, endCol + 1, 1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
    # Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
    rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

return rangeSelected


def renameFiles():
    print('Processing...')

    # Make a folder for the files
    current_directory = os.getcwd()
    folder_n_path = os.path.join(current_directory, folderDestination)
    print("Files saved to: " + folder_n_path)
    try:
    newFolder = os.makedirs(folder_n_path)

except:
    print("Folder already exists")
    return

# Get the Data to make the file names
selectedRange = copyRange(1, 1, 2, 2, file_names_sheet)
print(selectedRange)

for i, filename in zip(selectedRange, os.listdir(folderSource)):
    print(filename)
    file_name = str(i[0]) + " " + i[1] + ".jpg"
    filename = os.path.join(folderSource, filename)
    file_name = os.path.join(folderDestination, file_name)
    shutil.copy(filename, file_name)
    print("Done")

go = renameFiles()
```

I believe the issue is in the last bit of code but I cannot figure out how to do the loop. Thoughts?

Comment: run a print after each variable assignment in the loop and see if the value is as you would expect, that should help you resolve where your issue is quickly. for example: `for filename in os.listdir(folderSource): print(filename), filename = os.path.join(folderSource, filename) print(filename) file_name = os.path.join(folderDestination, file_name) print(file_name)` ... each print command should run on its own line.

Comment: So it is looping through the filenames in the folderSource directory fine, what it is not doing is moving to the next file_name in the list from the selectedRange: _first loop through:_ `C:/Users/jx00/Documents/PythonTest/Photos - Copy\000232.jpg.
 
Photos Renamed\000197 MC.jpg.`

_Second loop through it grabs the next photo but is still using the previous rename file_name:_
`C:/Users/jx00/Documents/PythonTest/Photos - Copy\000292.jpg.

Photos Renamed\Photos Renamed\000197 MC.jpg` Thoughts?

Comment: The line `    for i in range(startRow, endRow, 1): # Appends the row to a RowSelected list rowSelected = []` isn't doing anything. You aren't appending anything to this list. On another note, should `for j in range(startCol, endCol+1, 1):` be nested?

Comment: I see the edits, got it. For the last loop `for filename in os.listdir(folderSource):` It will iterate through every file in the folderSource, and add it to the first i in selected range (which is not what you want it to do I assume. Then it will add every filename in folderSource to the second iteration of i in selectedRange, which is apparently not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your last loop and let me know how it turns out, some modifications may need to be made since I can't see your data. It appears you want to run the for loop on the lists together, so try this:

```
for i, filename in zip(selectedRange, os.listdir(folderSource)):
    file_name = str(i[1]) + " " + i[2] + ".jpg"
    filename = os.path.join(folderSource, filename)
    file_name = os.path.join(folderDestination, file_name)
    shutil.copy(filename, file_name)
print(done)
go = renameFiles()
```

For nested for loop structures, consider the following:

```
loop1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
loop2 = ['f','g','h','i','j']
for i in loop1: # iterates through a,b,c,d,e
    print(i) #prints a,b,c,d,e
    for j in loop2: # compares all j objects of loop2 to i in loop 1:
        ij = i + j
        print(ij) # this will add all j's to each i
```

snippet output will add all j's to each iteration of i, before moving to the next iteration of i:

```
'af','ag','ah','ai','aj','bf','bg','bh','bi',bj'... etc
```

zipping 2 lists together, (which is what I did in the answer) compares each element in loop1 to loop2 at the same index in both lists:

```
for i,j in zip(loop1,loop2):
    ij = i + j
    print(ij)
```

output:

```
'af','bg','ch','di','ej'
```

The only thing you need to consider when you use the zip function for 2 lists, is that the iteration will only occur until the end of the shortest list. So if loop1 and loop2 were not equal lengths, then i+j would stop after the shorter list was complete. I hope this clarifies some of what I have done.

Comment: had to change the range but that worked perfectly. Yes that is what I was trying to do. So for my learning (I come from a bit of VBA) - it seemed like I was stuck in the lower `for loop` and not looping back up to the `selectedRange loop`. Is that correct? If so, in the future when I want to have nested `for loops` do I need to structure them like you did? all the variables in the first `for` code line and then reference them below? Thank you so much!

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you how nested for loops work.

Comment: @JasonDL see edits to answer to understand how the 2 different list traversions work.

Comment: I added an `if` statement so that the code would look for a file and then copy and rename it per the loop you helped me with. Code above is edited - the filesToFindRange list is loading properly but it keeps saying it cannot find the file. Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need that for loop inside of the if statement, the for loop in your if statement should be the top level for loop. Then you can include your if statement, `if filename in filesToFind:` do everything underneath. You don't need to include a for loop under the if statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179769/discussion-between-d-kennetz-and-jasondl).